# How to implement a "return" number with statements in EBNF?

Tags: grammar, ebnf

Here is my current grammar:

```
program         -> stmt-sequence
stmt-sequence   -> statement { TT_NEWLINE statement }
assign-stmt     -> var identifier TT_EQ factor
print-stmt      -> print factor
add-stmt        -> add factor TT_COMMA factor
sub-stmt        -> sub factor TT_COMMA factor
mul-stmt        -> mul factor TT_COMMA factor
div-stmt        -> div factor TT_COMMA factor
factor          -> number | identifier
```

For my math statements (`add-stmt`, `sub-stmt`, `mul-stmt`, `div-stmt`), I want those statements to return a number, like as if they were functions.

If you don't understand what I mean by "return", then here is one example:

```
print add 2, 4
```

I want for the math statement to be "replaced" with the number, the result of the statement from adding.

```
print 6
```

^
Basically, becoming like this.

```
factor          -> number | identifier | add-stmt | sub-stmt | mul-stmt | div-stmt
```

I do not know if adding alternations of the math statements in the factor is appropriate.

How can I basically be able allow these math statements to "return" in the EBNF grammar?

Answer (score 1):

The math statements should not contain the `return` terminal, it's not their part to define the `return` terminal/statement. Instead you define a new symbol like

```
return-stmt  -> TT_RETURN expr
```

After that you define what `expr` is. It is something which results in a value:

```
expr         -> factor | add-stmt | sub-stmt | mul-stmt | div-stmt
```

Be careful in how you define `return-stmt` and how you use the existing statements/expressions you have. You shouldn't be able to generate text/code like:

```
return return 4 + return 2 * 3
```